# how to delete files inside folder keeping last 15 days only

Tags: c#, vb.net, web-services, visual-studio-2012

i need to create web service or application using c#, to delete files from multiple paths for more than 15 days and insert log file "txt" for all files that been deleted for history and tracking, ?

am using VB 2012

thanks

Comment: i hope that's help. Search before posting such a simple question.  Dim directory As New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\YourDirectory")

        For Each file As IO.FileInfo In directory.GetFiles
            If (Now - file.CreationTime).Days > 7 Then file.Delete()
        Next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick for you.

**For C#**

```
using System.IO; 

string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dirName);

foreach (string file in files)
{
   FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
   if (fi.CreationTime < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-15))
      fi.Delete();
}
```

**For VB**

```
Dim directory As New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\YourDirectory")
For Each file As IO.FileInfo In directory.GetFiles
    If (Now - file.CreationTime).Days >= 15 Then
        file.Delete()
    End If
Next
```